# Implementing IDisposable - Disposable Fields vs. Disposable Properties

Tags: c#

I was running VS2013's code analysis on one of my current projects, and came across "CA1001: Types that own disposable fields should be disposable."  A simple example that generates the warning (presuming `DisposableClass` implements `IDisposable`) is:

```
class HasDisposableClassField
{
    private DisposableClass disposableClass;
}
```

However, converting the field variable to a property no longer generates the warning, even if the circumstance is that the property will be instantiated by the class:

```
class HasDisposableClassProperty
{
    private DisposableClass disposableClass { get; set; }
    public HasDisposableClassProperty()
    {
        disposableClass = new DisposableClass();
    }
}
```

In the first case it's clear that the class should implement the IDisposable pattern, and dispose of its `disposableClass` field appropriately.  My question: is the lack of a warning for the second case a limitation of the code analysis tool?  Should the class still implement IDisposable and dispose of the property, despite the lack of a warning?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, the lack of a warning is a limitation of the analysis tool.

You should definitely still implement `IDisposable` and clean up after yourself assuming your `IDisposable` properties aren't being injected from elsewhere.

Answer (score 9):

Yes; you still need to dispose it.

Putting something in a property does not magically dispose it for you.

The missing warning is a bug on Code Analysis (it ignores the backing field because it's compiler-generated)

Comment: Are you sure this is a bug and not intentional? Perhaps it doesn't consider a get/set property to be "owning" the disposable object.

Comment: @Gabe: Yes, but it should report it from compiler-generated backing field.

Comment: Why does the private backing field imply "ownership"?

Comment: @Gabe: How is it any different from any other field?

Comment: The warning is specifically for classes that *own* an `IDisposable`. That may be a bit hard to define, but having a private field of a type that implements `IDisposable` is a good indicator that you should be responsible for disposing of it because it's likely nobody else has a reference to it. Merely having a get/set property of type `IDisposable` doesn't imply that you own it, because anybody can set or get a reference to it.

Comment: @Gabe: But if you make a non-auto property exposing the field (which is identical what an auto property creates), it will warn.

Comment: Yes, but maybe the alerting on the *non*-auto property is the bug. It may not be smart enough to tell that the field is exposed as a property and thus generates a false positive. Can you think of any class that exposes any `IDisposable` properties and calls `Dispose` on them?

Comment: @Gabe: `StreamReader`

Comment: `StreamReader` exposes a getter, but not a setter. Passing a stream to the constructor is a clear transfer of ownership, and obviously it should close any stream it opens. This is clearly a different scenario from having an `IDisposable` auto-property.

Answer (score 3):

Implementation of disposable should depend on how the resources that need disposing (whether disposable or non-managed) are created.

If your object **receives a resource via injection** (constructor, method or property), it probably does not own it and should therefore probably not dispose of it.

How the resource is stored (local variable, field or property (with backing field) is not important), however, you may need to check that your resource hasn't been dispose externally, as your object isn't its owner.

If your class **creates a resource directly** (via create, allocate, open handle, factory method), it probably does own it and should therefore probably dispose of it.

The problem is that most static code analysis tools have limited rule sets and therefore can not make such distinctions and instead try to cover the cases they consider more common.